# CSS ISSUE with HTML

Tags: html, css

i have color issue with css. when i put HREF in link the font color changes to grey but there is no grey color in its class in css.
The code is below.

```
 HTML
<a class="css_button_addHRS"  >ADD HOURS</a>
```

When i add href in the tag it changes the font color of ADD HOURS to grey it should be white. Any Idea? There is no other grey A in css.

```
CSS


 .css_button_addHRS {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: inherit;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        border: 1px solid #d02718;
        padding: 9px 18px;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #810E05;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 0px #f5978e;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
        display: inline-block;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#f24537",endColorstr="#c62d1f");
    }

        .css_button_addHRS:hover {
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #f24537 5%, #c62d1f 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(180deg, #c62d1f 5%, #f24537 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#c62d1f",endColorstr="#f24537");
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .css_button_addHRS:active {
            position: relative;
            top: 1px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
```

this css creates a button rounded corner in red color with white font color. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: looks white to me http://jsfiddle.net/fLy1mpLw/

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify This. The page links will automatically change to default color of links, so you have to add this:

```
<style type="text/css">

    a:link,
    a:visited,
    a:hover,
    a:active{
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
```

What editor do you use to code?

Comment: i use dreamweaver cs6

Comment: This worked :D THANK YOU MATE. i uses .css_button_addHRS: link { and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's default styling of a `:visited` link.

You should add this to fix it:

```
.css_button_addHRS:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `link`, `visited` and `active` colors, if not specified, take the defaults values set by the browser, and it varies across browsers. Since you already specified a color for `.css_button_addHRS` class, the grey color surely appears when you have visited the link,so you have to specify a color for visited links, e.g:

```
.css_button_addHRS:visited{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Hope it's useful!